# Redirect index page to different file then the rest of the redirects using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Not sure how to pull this off.  Say I have example.com and example2.com.  I want all requests from example2.com to  301 redirect to example.com.  That part isn't hard.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

What I would like to do though when someone enters www.example2.com is to have them redirected to www.example.com/a-special-page.html and have everything else redirect exactly as entered.  ie www.example2.com/another-page.html redirects to www.example.com/another-page.html

Answer (score 0):

Have specific redirect first and then the generic redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/a-special-page.html [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.